# Is storing data in a file a good idea?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, electron

I'm planning on programming a desktop app with Electron right now and I need to store data somewhere, but I'm not sure what to use (a database would be to heavy for this app).

I have data like this:

```
{ firstname: John,
  lastname: Doe,
  age: 25,
  id: 1337,
  ... }
```

And I'm thinking about creating a data.json file and store those kind of objects in an JSON-Array. Whenever I need data or want to query for certain objects I would use the **fs** module from npm.

So my question is if this is a good idea? (also in view of speed and best practice) 
Thanks!:)

So is storing JSON objects in a file (JSON array) is a good idea at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Electron App with Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32220970/electron-app-with-database)

Comment: As you pointed out, if you need to query, you'll be using `fs` directly, which is usually a pain. I marked as duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32220970/electron-app-with-database, which provides suggestions for storing data with Electron apps.

Comment: first of all thanks for your comments. I was thinking about using a client-side database like PouchDB aswell. But still I'm not sure if storing data in a file is a good idea at all (last sentence in question)

Comment: No prob. Generally no, if it's data you're going to "query", I would say go with a database. If you're just storing files where you can predict the name of the file beforehand, and you're going to retrieve the entire file every time (media storage, basic document storage, etc.), then yes the file system is a great place.

Comment: Yes i think that's a good approach. I think i will use a database then. thanks